# Sometimes cannot connect to a remote DB2 database

Tags: properties, db2, host, required

I'm having some issues when trying to connect to a remote DB2 database. The strange thing here is that sometimes it's OK but sometimes not, i.e. I cannot always reproduce this behaviour.

The error is the following:

```
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlNonTransientConnectionException: [jcc][t4][10380][11951][3.64.114] Required property "<DB_NAME>" is unknown host. ERRORCODE=-4222, SQLSTATE=08001
```

Where DB_NAME is the name of my host. The address can be resolved always using ping and nslookup. As I said, this only occurs from time to time. Does anyone know this issue? Maybe some configuration restriction on the number of active connections or X connections in a time bucket policy?

Comment: Did you check your network? is there any short outage that prevent the connectivity from the Java App to the dabase?

Comment: Hi.Thanks for replying. Yes indeed I checked the network but I found out yesterday the database also needs to resolve the address and sometimes it wasn't able to do so hence the error.

Comment: I wrote the same answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, there are network issues that prevents the connection between the application (Java) and the database server, thus the database server cannot be resolved.

Please check the network to find errors.